Communicating with Keysight scope (USBTMC - Python)
Hello I'm trying to communicate with a Keysight oscilloscope to get the waveform saved as a CSV or PNG image to the computer without using Pathwave Benchvue software.
import pyvisa
import os
import libusb
# import libusb_package
# import usb.core
import usb.backend.libusb1
import usbtmc
from usbmonitor import USBMonitor
from usbmonitor.attributes import ID_MODEL, ID_MODEL_ID, ID_VENDOR_ID


monitor = USBMonitor()
devices_dict = monitor.get_available_devices()
for device_id, device_info in devices_dict.items():
    print(f"{device_id} -- {device_info[ID_MODEL]} ({device_info[ID_MODEL_ID]} - {device_info[ID_VENDOR_ID]})")

# dev = usb.core.find()
# print("dev", dev)
# for dev in libusb_package.find(find_all=True):
#    print(dev)

adr = "USB::0x2A8D::0x1766::MY57251874::INSTR"
p_id = 0x1766
v_id = 0x2A8D

# device = usb.core.find(idVendor=v_id, idProduct=p_id)
# instr = usbtmc.Instrument(v_id, p_id)
instr = usbtmc.Instrument(adr)
print(instr.ask("*IDN?"))

The output of usbmonitor shows the scope connected with USB to the laptop.
USB\VID_2A8D&PID_1766\MY57251874 -- USB Test and Measurement Device (IVI) (1766 - 2A8D)

I have the following error :
 instr = usbtmc.Instrument(adr)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\usbtmc\usbtmc.py", line 262, in __init__
    raise UsbtmcException("Device not found", 'init')
usbtmc.usbtmc.UsbtmcException: Device not found [init]


Try to change your address string from:
adr = "USB::0x2A8D::0x1766::MY57251874::INSTR"

to:
adr = "USB0::0x2A8D::0x1766::MY57251874::INSTR"

Notice the additional "0" at the end of "USB" at the beginning of your address string.
